# Why is the cursor icon not changing on drag/drop ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop

I am trying to drag child component it works good but i could not change the cursor icon.
I tried in child and parent, it changed with dragover(on parent) event but i dont want that icon. Do you have solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use drag and drop events for drag and drop. Use mouse events for changing cursor(and also drag and drop). Drag and drop events have different meaning for browsers like drag and drop files,images.